# Javascript slider questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a slider script.

**JS Code:**

```
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#slides").slidesjs({
        start: 3,
        width: 940,
        height: 10
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Once the html or php is loaded, the slider starts, all is well.

**Question1:** No where in the page explicitly tells this function to load, how does it get loaded? Is it the $ sign in front of `$(function()` some kind of shorthand from jQuery for document `.ready` or something like that?

**Question2:** When I put an `alert()` right after $(function(){, the alert pops up with this message: `function (a,b){return new m.fn.init(a,b)}`
**What does it mean?**

**Code:**

```
<script>
  var sf=6,
    $(function(sf){
      $("#slides").slidesjs({
        start: sf,
        width: 940,
        height: 10
      });
    });
  </script>
```

**How to go about doing this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A1** - yes, `$(function(){});` is self executing function. It differs from `.ready` in that way, that `.ready` will be executed only when DOM is ready, while `$(function(){});` will be executed as soon as this code is reached by parser.

**A2** not clear. `alert()` is not valid, because it need to have some content passed in. You can pass function name to and it will alert function description.